# How to transform problem to convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-system

I have the following problem
$$min \{ x^TAx + 2b^Tx + c : \|x\|_2 <=1
\}$$
where $$A \in R^{n x n}, b \in R^n, c\in R$$
I need to show that this problem can be transformed to convex optimization problem.

What I did:
By Spectral decomposition theorem $$A = UDU^T$$ thus replacing it $$min \{x^TUDU^Tx + 2b^TUU^Tx + c : \|U^Tx\|_2 <=1 \}$$ where $$\|U^Tx\| = \|x\|$$.
By changing variable $$y=U^Tx$$ we will get $$y^TDy + 2b^TUy + c : \|y\|_2 <=1$$

how to proceed ? I want to have problem in form of the sum of matrix elements.

Comment: How do you define convex optimization problem? What do we know about $A$? You can't just use the spectral decomposition problem. You need prerequisites for that.

Comment: You can write $${x}^T{A}{x} + {a}^T{x} + b=(x-x_0)^TA(x-x_0)+c.$$

It follows that $$-x_0^TAx-x^TAx_0=-2x_0^TAx=a^Tx,\qquad x_0^TAx_0+c=b.$$

Comment: Your calculations remember me this [conic-quadratic-modeling](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#conic-quadratic-modeling).